# Is there a benefit for apps written with react-native in doing security scans before building apk/ipa?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

For Android and iOS apps developed using react-native, I’m wondering if a static vulnerability scan against the javascript code is necessary prior to building the ipa and apk?  Would doing this type of scan catch things that would not be caught when doing vulnerability scans against the actual ipa and apk?

I’m wondering if it is worth adding something like GitLab’s NodeJsScan to our CI/CD or if it would just be overkill.

Comment: If you're wanting to be 100% comfortable the packages you're using in your app do not have any vulnerabilities then go for it. You could use `npm audit` with a precommit hook to check for vulnerabilities. From npm: "npm audit automatically runs when you install a package with npm install." However, this doesn't check for peerDependencies.